# How to swap rows in 2 pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, swap

Given two `pandas dataframes` and a random number `x`how can I 'crossover' the dataframes at point x?

random number:

```
x = 9
```

df1:

```
                Values
Parameters            
Kcd          99.789468
ka           55.137982
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      17.842956
Ki            3.756849
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr            0.089625
PR1           4.000462
PR2          12.485559
alpha         1.000000
Klid          1.404747
```

df2:

```
                Values
Parameters            
Kcd          43.576215
ka           24.103700
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      96.228737
Ki            3.910448
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr           57.097216
PR1           3.999886
PR2          14.623385
alpha         1.000000
Klid          0.420894
```

desired output

child1:

```
                Values
Parameters            
Kcd          43.576215
ka           24.103700
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      96.228737
Ki            3.910448
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr           57.097216
PR1           3.999886
PR2          12.485559
alpha         1.000000
Klid          1.404747
```

child 2

```
                Values
Parameters            
Kcd          99.789468
ka           55.137982
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      17.842956
Ki            3.756849
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr            0.089625
PR1           4.000462
PR2          14.623385
alpha         1.000000
Klid          0.420894
```

as you can see, the algorithm should go to the 9th element of both `df1` and `df2` and exchange their information at point `x`

Comment: Does `df1['Values'].iloc[x-1], df2['Values'].iloc[x-1] = df2['Values'].iloc[x-1], df1['Values'].iloc[x-1]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) and swap values with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
x = 9
df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:], df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:] = 
df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:].copy(), df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:].copy()
print df1
Parameters            
Kcd          99.789468
ka           55.137982
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      17.842956
Ki            3.756849
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr            0.089625
PR1           4.000462
PR2          14.623385
alpha         1.000000
Klid          0.420894
print df2
                Values
Parameters            
Kcd          43.576215
ka           24.103700
CID           0.000000
TGFbeta      96.228737
Ki            3.910448
Total_LR1R2  18.604000
Kr           57.097216
PR1           3.999886
PR2          12.485559
alpha         1.000000
Klid          1.404747
```

For testing `DataFrames` were changed:

```
print df1
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               1
ka                2
CID               3
TGFbeta           4
Ki                5
Total_LR1R2       6

print df2
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               7
ka                8
CID               9
TGFbeta          10
Ki               11
Total_LR1R2      12
```

```
x = 4
df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:], df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:] = 
df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:].copy(), df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:].copy()
print df1
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               1
ka                2
CID               3
TGFbeta          10
Ki               11

print df2
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               7
ka                8
CID               9
TGFbeta           4
Ki                5
Total_LR1R2       6
```

If do not use `copy()`, values are changed only in one `df`:

```
df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:], df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:] = 
df1['Values'].iloc[x-1:], df2['Values'].iloc[x-1:]

print df1
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               1
ka                2
CID               3
TGFbeta           4
Ki                5
Total_LR1R2       6
print df2
             Values
Parameters         
Kcd               7
ka                8
CID               9
TGFbeta           4
Ki                5
Total_LR1R2       6
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!